# Spam flags: Convert links to plaintext and discourage edits

Tags: feature-request, spam

As soon as a post has been flagged as spam, any links contained in it should be converted to plain text (even if there's a nofollow set). Additionally, when trying to edit such a post users should receive a notice to discourage them from removing the spam content but rather flagging it as spam, too.

The advantages of this would be:

- People not accidentally clicking malicious/spammy links
- Moderators not having to check the post history to see where the spam is

Comment: I have [an old feature request that would educate users about spam flags when they try to act on the post (e.g. downvoting or flagging as NAA)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148691/151385). The same mechanism would certainly make sense for user that try to edit spam.

Comment: You may have to revisit the **As soon as a post has been flagged as spam** part because a spam flag may get declined.

Comment: One disadvantage is that instead of serial downvoting, serial spam flagging will be more effective.

Comment: One easy way to avoid most abuse would be to restrict this to 1 rep (or low-rep) users. Almost all spam is posted by 1 rep users anyway.

Comment: what about spam flags submitted by mistake? Is it considered OK to de-linkify and lock editing of non spam posts? If yes, how can a mis-flagged legitimate poster recover?

Comment: @gnat in that case, when a moderator reviews the flag, they would reject it and the delinking and lock would be removed. Spam flags have the highest priority in the moderator queue IIRC.

Comment: @ColeJohnson this is non currently spelled in this feature request. If flag rejection would really roll it all back, I probably would be happy with proposed feature

Answer (score 1):

This proposal seems to come down to:

- users with edit privileges should be discouraged from removing spam themselves;
- potential spam should be left in place for moderators to see;
- the potential spam can be made harmless by de-linking it.

The downsides:

- I'm not so sure that "harmless" is accurate — even delinked, spam is spam and copy/pasting the link could be dangerous to more naive users; how fast are spamflags acted on? Quicker than edits? How long would this de-linked spam remain up before the post got deleted?
- you could avoid this by clearly marking the post as having been spamflagged, but that's not at all fair to authors whose content has an *invalid* spam flag attached to it, for whatever length of time.

The upside:

- high-rep users would still get to contribute to spam removal, it's just that they would be encouraged to only do so by way of spam flags;

Since moderators will likely wish to respond to a valid spam flag with action that transcends simply content removal (say, account suspension), this seems fairly reasonable to me.