# See who handled your flag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, moderators

**What?**

I propose to add a possibility on "helpful flags" page to see who has handled that flag (what moderator/community manager). It may be shown on mouseover.

**Why?**

Because I want to see who has handled my flag and eventually contact him in that case.

Comment: And how would you contact an individual moderator?

Comment: If you need to discuss a flag decision then meta is probably the place to do it

Comment: No, no, no. We don't need to add ways for users to hassle other users or moderators.

Comment: And what are you going to say to the flag handler?

Comment: The mods are a team.  There is no need to contact a specific one to discuss specific flags.  If you have a question as why a specific action was taken, then ask a question on meta to get the input of the community.  If the specific moderator who handled your flag feels it necessary to chime in, they will.

Comment: Not all flags are handled by moderators or community managers

Comment: Even if you figured out who the flag handler is, what would you say to them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nah, let's not. If there is a problem with a flag, or you don't understand why it was handled the way it was handled, come to Meta and ask a question.

If you think a moderator is going over certain boundaries, use the contact option to contact the team and explain the situation.

There is no way to directly contact a moderator, and it's not really the path you should take anyway.

Comment: And just to be clear in addition, there are records of who handled flags and what they did. If something egregious happened, it can be handled by the staff.

Comment: And if necessary, with a staff as well @AndrewBarber.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess the promise not to hit people with a stick at Stack Exchange only applies to employees, so; yeah!

Comment: I do NOT recommend coming to meta for asking that question.

Comment: Then don't @LaszloPapp. And if it's a really serious issue that can't be handled by moderators or the community, just contact the team.

Comment: @Bart: obviously.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a question regarding how a flag was handled Meta is the place to do that, as such community opinion can be sought. Directly replying to a moderator is likely to lead only to disagreement and badgering moderators to support your view which is ultimately not constructive.

In a best case scenario all moderators would make the same decision; guided by community opinion. As such discussing with the particular moderator who handled your flag is unnecessary

Comment: Yup; and I know many of us keep an eye on questions here regarding actions we took - and notify others for the same. Often, if a specific reply is needed, the moderator in question could respond. Not always, because sometimes others answer the concern quite well. [That said, here's an example of mine from just now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202997/flagging-questions-as-spam-versus-editing-out-advertising-links/203000#203000)

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter who handled the flag, if there is an issue with your flag status then you can always come to meta and discuss it. So I don't think it would be a a good feature to have. Infact leaving it as anonymous serves a better purpose. If the flag is helpful then there is no need to contact moderators *(already busy with moderation)* and if it is declined then most of the time a reason is provided why it was declined and if you are not happy with the reason then you can come to meta to discuss it.